# Definition of injection and the meaning of codomain

Tags: real-analysis, functions, random-variables

As far as I understand, the main difference between bijective and injective functions are that the codomain of injective could contain some elements that is not in the image of $f:X \rightarrow Y$ where $X$ is domain and $Y$ is codomain.

My question is: Why do we need to define a codomain? If nothing will be mapped to those elements that are in the codomain but not in the image, why can't we just redefine the codomain just to be the image? When we talk about a function/map, what is the point of defining this codomain?

Comment: We might not know the range of $f$ precisely and writing $f:X\to f(X)$ is less informative in this case (since it is tautological!) than knowing a larger set $Y$ such that $f(x)\in Y$ for all $x\in X$. There may be better justifications, but that is one thing I could think of immediately.

Comment: Also, a lot of the time we don’t need to know the range itself. Oftentimes the range of a function is very complex and hard to describe, but we can easily determine a codomain for it, and often that’s good enough for what we need.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation here. They help!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Two basic reasons:

1. Often it will be both difficult and pointless to compute the image of a function. Suppose we want to write down some polynomial function $p(x) = \sum_{i=0} a_i x^i$. This defines a function $p : \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$, not necessarily surjective; do you really want to compute the minimum and maximum of this polynomial in order to find out what its image is if you don't have to? What if $p$ was something more complicated than a polynomial?
2. We often want to say things not about a single function but about multiple functions. For example here is a statement you might want to make: if $X$ is a set, the collection of all functions $f : X \to \mathbb{R}$ (not necessarily surjective) forms a [vector space](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vector_space) under pointwise addition and scalar multiplication. E.g. if $f, g : X \to \mathbb{R}$ are two such functions, so is $f + g$. This statement is *false* if we require functions to be surjective, and if we were forced to talk about images we'd have to say something awkward like "if $f$ and $g$ are two functions whose image is a subset of $\mathbb{R}$ then..." Surjectivity simply is not important here; what's important is that the functions take values in $\mathbb{R}$ and real numbers can be added and multiplied. There are countless other examples like this.